# Change of jsp page are not reflected in .class file

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

i am working on an old java EE webapp with eclipse. When i change the code of a jsp page, eclipse autopublish correctly on tomcat but in runtime with the browser I don't see the differencies. If i go in apache-tomcat/webApp/MyAppFolder and I open the jsp source just modified I see the changes. I try to delete the browser cache but nothing , i tried also to restart the tomcat but still the same. I think that tomcat doesn't compile jsp pages deployed by eclipse. Infact the last modified value of the .class file doesn't change.

Comment: There's a folder under the Tomcat install directory `/work/Catalina/[hostname]`. Delete the contents and try again.

Comment: @acdhirr the folder contains antother folder with the app name but is empty. I tried to remove it but the problem still remains

Comment: Exactly which .class file doesn't change? Tomcat by default stores compiled jsp files in the /work folder. E.g. `home.jsp` will in its compiled form be available at `/work/Catalina/[domain]/appname/org/apache/jsp`

Comment: Doesn't change .class files stored in apache-tomcat/webApps/[appName]/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp  . In the /work/Catalina/localhost/[appName]/ folder there aren't files. This app was imported in eclipse from the apache/webApp folder, could be this the problem?

Comment: Yes, sounds like a faulty project setup. In Eclipse you have to create a `Dynamic Web Project`, import all the java source and jsp files, along with the necessary libraries, web.xml etc. (did I forget anything?) then build a `.war` which you can deploy to Tomcat.

Comment: When I imported this project I used the import function of eclipse and I used as input the war extracted from tomcat webapp library. So with the wizard I configured a new web project but i don't know if it is dynamic. With your solution I must create a war and everytime deploy manually the application?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Spring Boot automatic restart. it will help you update your projects.
follow the link for details:

[enter link description here](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-automatic-restart-using-spring-boot-devtools)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).